# Questions are not updated after "Next" button is pressed

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui

I'm working on a quiz app, and stacked with updating the UI with the next set of questions. The first set is loading just fine, but when I'm trying to get the next set of question by clicking on the "Next" button - nothing happened. When I tried debugging, I noticed that instead of updating the questions, the questions are added to the previous set of questions. Please help me figure out what am I doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
import Foundation
import Combine

final class QuizManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var quizQuestions: [QuizModel] = Bundle.main.decode("file.json")
    
    var imageIndex = 0
    var possibleAnswers = [String]()
    var correctAnswers = 0
    var questionsAsked = 0
    
    init() {
        getRandomQuestion()
    }
    
    
    func getRandomQuestion() {
        
            imageIndex = Int.random(in: 0..<quizQuestions.count)
            if quizQuestions[imageIndex].isCompleted {
                imageIndex = Int.random(in: 0..<quizQuestions.count)
            }
        
        
        possibleAnswers.append(quizQuestions[imageIndex].description)
        
        
        var index1 = Int.random(in: 0..<quizQuestions.count)
        var index2 = Int.random(in: 0..<quizQuestions.count)

        if index1 == imageIndex && index1 == index2 {
            index1 = Int.random(in: 0..<quizQuestions.count)
        } else {
            possibleAnswers.append(quizQuestions[index1].description)
        }

        if index2 == imageIndex && index1 == index2 {
            index2 = Int.random(in: 0..<quizQuestions.count)
        } else {
            possibleAnswers.append(quizQuestions[index2].description)
        }

        possibleAnswers.shuffle()
    }

    func checkAnswer(answer: String) -> Bool {
        questionsAsked += 1
        
        if quizQuestions[imageIndex].description == answer {
            correctAnswers += 1
        }
        quizQuestions[imageIndex].isCompleted = true
        return quizQuestions[imageIndex].description == answer
    }
    
    
} 



import SwiftUI

struct QuizQestionsView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var quizManager = QuizManager()
    
    @State private var isCorrect = false
    @State private var correctAnswer = 0
    @State private var answerSelected = ""
    @State private var isTapped = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ImageView(name: quizManager.quizQuestions[quizManager.imageIndex].image,
                                          contentMode: .scaleAspectFit,
                                          tintColor: .black)
                                    .frame(minWidth: 150, idealWidth: 200, maxWidth: 250, minHeight: 150, idealHeight: 200, maxHeight: 250)
                
                Spacer()
                
                
                VStack {
                    ForEach(quizManager.possibleAnswers, id: \.self) { answer in
                        QuestionsView(answer: answer) {
                            self.isCorrect = self.quizManager.checkAnswer(answer: answer)
                            self.answerSelected = answer
                            self.isTapped = true
                        }
                        .disabled(isTapped)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16.0)
                                .stroke(getColor(answer), lineWidth: 1)
                        )
                    }
                }
                Spacer()

                Button(action: {
                    self.quizManager.getRandomQuestion()
                }) {
                    Text("NEXT")
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    
    func getColor(_ tag: String) -> Color {
        if answerSelected == tag {
            if isCorrect {
                return Color.green
            } else {
                return Color.red
            }
        } else {
            if isTapped && !isCorrect {
                if tag == quizManager.quizQuestions[quizManager.imageIndex].description {

                    return Color.green
                }
            }
        }
        return Color.accentColor
    }
```

The QuestionsView looks like this:

```
        var answer: String
        var onTap: () -> Void

        var body: some View {
            Button(action: {
                self.onTap()
            }) {
                Text(answer)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `getRandomQuestion()`, as you've already figured out, all of your code appends to the end of the array.

At the beginning of the function, you could clear out the array:

```
func getRandomQuestion() {
  possibleAnswers = []

  //the rest of the existing code here
}
```

Comment: For some reason, the "next" button doesn't respond

Comment: `possibleAnswers` should probably also be `@Published`